# i want to remove un-necessary joins from my following query to increse the efficiency.

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

i have this code

```
select sales.customerid ,name1.FullName as CustomerName, sales.managerID ,  name2.FullName as ManagerName, sales.BranchID ,name3.FullName as BranchName, EmployeeID ,name4.FullName as EmployeeName

     from dbo.Sales as sales
    join dbo.name as name1 on name.id = sales.customerid
    join dbo.name as name2 on name.id = sales.managerid
    join dbo.name as name3 on name.id = sales.branchid
    join dbo.name as name4 on name.id = sales.employeeid
```

How can i reduce the join count to 1 instead of multiple joins with the same table?

Comment: If you have an index on `name(id)`, then your version should be quite efficient.  You might want `left join`s if some of the ids don't match.

Comment: check query. I think should be: *join dbo.name as name1 on name**1**.id = sales.customerid*

Comment: Just have `AND` statements instead of additional joins

Comment: You can reduce the join count but not the efficiency (and presumably not the readability).

Comment: If you _need_ all the values in your select clause, and if the customer, manager, branch and employee could all potentially be different, then I don't think there are any unnecessary joins in that statement.

Comment: I'd suggest LEFT JOIN's instead, will return a result even if one of the names are missing!

Comment: How long does it take for the query to run presently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At present there is nothing wrong with your current query although you may not find it aesthetically pleasing.
If it is running slow you could try adding indexes or these are some alternatives though I'm not saying they are better:

Using Cross Apply:

```
select s.customerid , cust.FullName as CustomerName, s.managerID, man.FullName as ManagerName,
s.BranchID, bran.FullName as BranchName, EmployeeID, empl.FullName as EmployeeName
    from dbo.Sales as s
    CROSS APPLY
    (Select n.FullName
    from dbo.name as n
    where n.id = s.customerid) cust
    CROSS APPLY
    (Select n.FullName
    from dbo.name as n
    where n.id = s.managerid) man
    CROSS APPLY
    (Select n.FullName
    from dbo.name as n
    where n.id = s.branchid) bran
    CROSS APPLY
    (Select n.FullName
    from dbo.name as n
    where n.id = s.employeeid) empl
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bae69/1/0

Answer (score 3):

Other than your aliases, you query is fine. If it is slow, then the columns need indexed.

If you REALLY want to get rid of the joins, then your only option is to alter the schema. You could include the primary key still, but add the name of the person that corresponds to that ID.

Personally, I'd stick with the JOINs. If find yourself writing the same join over and over, it may be a good spot for a view.